# Flexdashboard within R Markdown website

Tags: r-markdown

Is there a way to embed flexdashboard within an R Mardown website? In other words, I would have a few files:

**YAML file**

```
name: "Flex"
navbar:
  title: "Flex"
  type: inverse
  left:
    - text: "Page1"
      href: page1.html
output:
  html_document:
    theme: cerulean
    css: custom.css
```

**index file**

```
---
title: "Untitled"
---

Flex website
```

page1.Rmd

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

I would like to do this because it will be easier to work in multiple (smaller) R Markdown files and it provides the flexibility of knitting individual pages.